# casting a json referenced by a dynamic type parameter to a Idictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, idictionary

I've come across the following code that doesn't work

```
public void Execute(dynamic options){
   var dictionary = options as IDictionary<string,object>();//i saw the dictionary is always null but the developer is says it suppose to work!
}
```

where the options holds a json

```
[{Id :1212, Page : 12, SortColumn : "Name", SortBy : "ASC"}]
```

My question is does this suppose to work? I mean hei is it possible to cast a json which is referenced by a dynamic type to a IDictionary without any blackmagic?

Comment: You could use an `object` type as a parameter. Or implement a Dynamic Dictionary. Take a look: http://reyrahadian.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/creating-a-dynamic-dictionary-with-c-4-dynamic/